# "FINDSTR:" Error when using special characters in a call function (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a game, and want to color the dialogues different characters say. Everything works well, but only if I'm not using '?' in the call function used to color the text (Comes up as a FINDSTR error). However, I can use an exclamation point with no problems. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Just in case, I've included the code that colors the text.

***EDIT: This part goes at the very top of the batch file.***

```
 for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
 set "DEL=%%a"
)
```

***This part goes at the bottom of the batch file.***

```
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

This is the error that comes up:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
FINDSTR: Cannot open  'When did it get so dark outside?' It was morning a few minutes ago...
```

Comment: The `i` in the last line of code is a typo, right? Please provide a sample command line how you call the given routine and tell us what `%DEL%` is set to...

Comment: Doubt that `i` is a typo. This is how i'd call the routine: `call :colorEcho [color] "Text"` `%DEL%` is set to `%%a`.

Comment: The `i` is indeed a typo but it does not harm apparently; please include the `call` command line into your question post...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did some digging around and found a way around this. It's possible to use special characters such as `?`, `*`, `:`, `\`, `/`, `"`, `<`, `>`, and `|`.

***Put this at the very top of the batch file:***

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)

rem Prepare a file "X" with only one dot
<nul > X set /p ".=."
```

***Put this at the very bottom of the batch file:***

```
:colorEcho
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
exit /b
```

***Use this format to color the text:***

`call :colorEcho [color] "Text"`

E.g. `call :colorEcho C "Red"`

This uses the rule for valid path/filenames.
If a `\..\` is in the path the prefixed element will be removed completely and it's not necessary that this element contains only valid filename characters.

***EDIT: Not able to use `!`. Will investigate further.***

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is a wildcard for a single character (similar to the `*` which is a wildcard for a character sequence). Such characters are not allowed in file names.

The first line of the error message comes from the redirection `> "%~2"` as you cannot use wildcards for the redirection target, you need to specify a dedicated file there.

The second line of the error message comes indeed from `findstr`, which expects the command line argument after the search string to be a path pointing to an existing file or files. Since the redirection failed as said before, no file has been created.

Since `findstr` prints filenames in colour it is obvious that you can only use characters that are allowed in file names. Hence the following ones are forbidden: `?`, `*`, `:`, `\`, `/`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`.

By the way, the `i` at the end of in the last command line `del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i` should be removed.

Comment: How will I go about fixing this?